# Visual Studio Code offline package installation

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, nuget-package

Is there any possibility to install offline NuGet package from **visual studio code** without internet connection

I have tried following command but invain

PS C:\Users\vscode> Install-Package svcutil -Source C:\Users\Downloads\nuget\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was resolved by following command

dotnet tool install --global --add-source path-to-your-nuget-package tool-name

**Example** 
dotnet tool install --global --add-source D:\nugetpackages dotnet-svcutil